# Creating event returns ErrorPropertyValidationFailure

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to create an Event via Microsoft Graph by providing following JSON input:

```json
{
  "subject": "Test event",
  "organizer": {
    "emailAddress": {
      "name": "Name 1",
      "address": "name1@graffter.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-10-18T01:45:38",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-10-18T04:45:38",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "Name 2",
        "address": "name2@graffter.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      "type": "required"
    },
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "room",
        "address": "room@graffter.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      "type": "resource"
    }
  ],
  "body": {
    "content": "Prueba de evento",
    "contentType": "HTML"
  },
  "location": {
    "displayName": "room",
    "locationEmailAddress": "room@graffter.onmicrosoft.com"
  }
}
```

Sometimes, however, I'm getting the following error response (and I mean sometimes) :

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorPropertyValidationFailure",
    "message": "At least one property failed validation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "9f528d43-ed74-4c02-a29c-f01e47f24717",
      "date": "2018-10-18T12:14:31"
    }
  }
}
```

So the thing is, with the same code and the same JSON request (changing dates of course), it sometimes worked while others times it fails.

I'm following the [official documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_events), I have all the permissions needed, and the `access_token` I'm using works perfectly with other API calls such as `/messages`.

Comment: If a given payload fails, will it _always_ fail? In other words, if you receive an `ErrorPropertyValidationFailure` and simply resubmit, is it accepted by the API or will it continue even through multiple retries?

Comment: Yes, the same request with the same payload sometimes works and others not.

Comment: Does you try change "contentType" value to "Text". For example: "contentType":" Text"